# Get sum of all columns greater than 0 except the highest values

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Group   Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4
A        -94    96         16   -92
B         30    59        -10    44
C         50    -18       -30    24
D         61    49        -15   -95
```

I need to find the sum of all positive values in each group except the highest value to get the following:

```
Group   Sum
A       16
B       74
C       24
D       49
```

for group A, I ignored 96 and only 16 was used to get sum of 16.

for group B, I ignored 59 and 30, 44 was used to get sum of 74

If there is only 1 positive value, we keep them we don't drop any values.

I am not sure how to do the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.set_index('Group')
df.where(df.ne(df.max(axis=1), axis=0) & (df > 0)).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
Group
A    16.0
B    74.0
C    24.0
D    49.0
dtype: float64
```

Details:

Find max on each row, look for values in that row that are not equal to that max AND values greater than zero then sum with axis=1.

Or..

```
df.mask(df<0).sum(1) - df.max(1)
```

Output:

```
Group
A    16.0
B    74.0
C    24.0
D    49.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer, interested to see a solution without loops:

```
df = df.set_index('Group')  # (if necessary)

# set max value in each row to zero if more than one positive
for k,v in df.loc[(df > 0).sum(1) > 1].idxmax(1).to_dict().items()
    df.at[k,v] = 0

np.where(df > 0, df, 0).sum(1)
> array([16, 74, 24, 49])
```

Comment: Why is it not setting to 0 the value of 16 for group A and affecting the sum

Comment: Because it only sets the maximum value in each row to 0

Answer (score 2):

Use [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) to remove the negative values, perform a simple [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), then subtract the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
df2 = df.set_index('Group')

out = df2.clip(lower=0).sum(1).sub(df2.max(1)).reset_index(name='Sum')
```

Extended version, don't subtract if there is a single positive:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Group')
MAX = df2.max(1)
out = df2.clip(lower=0).sum(1)
out = out.sub(MAX.where(out.gt(MAX), 0)).reset_index(name='Sum')
```

output:

```
  Group  Sum
0     A   16
1     B   74
2     C   24
3     D   49
```

intermediates:

```
df2.clip(lower=0)
       Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
Group                        
A         0    96    16     0
B        30    59     0    44
C        50     0     0    24
D        61    49     0     0

df2.clip(lower=0).sum(1)
Group
A    112
B    133
C     74
D    110
dtype: int64

df2.max(1)
Group
A    96
B    59
C    50
D    61
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Clever! Didn't think of subtracting the max - I had a feeling it could be vectorised :) (but note OP's condition that if there is only one positive value in the row you shouldn't remove it, your answer should add that)

Comment: @Josh you could also use a boolean mask (for instance if you want to handle the top2 max, of if there are several maxes

Comment: @Josh good point (I hadn't seen that part), see update ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work too.

```
df.set_index('Group', inplace= True)

# Removing all the -ve values
cond = df[['Val1','Val2','Val3','Val4']] >= 0 
df1 = df.where(cond)

# Removing all the max values from each row
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df1.replace(row.max(), np.nan, inplace= True)

print(df1.sum(axis =1)) # Sum the output
```

Output:

```
Group
A    16.0
B    74.0
C    24.0
D    49.0
```